# Create a function to get similar sounding wordds using Soundex

Tags: sql

I want to create a function to get a list of similar sounding words when I input a word in SQL. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question as an MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - show code examples of what you've already attempted and/or examples of input and expected output in order to help us help you.